# What causes a form to shift from its saved screen position when reloading?

Tags: python, forms, pyqt5, qgis

When implementing the `frm_obj.setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, h_dim, v_dim)` method to restore saved position and size, the form will sometimes shift 31px up and 8px left of the saved position.  The 31px appears to be the height of the title bar; I have no idea where the 8px difference derives from.  I can add a `move()` function with the same values for x and y after the `setGeometry()` to correct it; however, it then may (or may not) move *down and right* 31 and 8 px, respectively.

What would cause this and how can I check for that condition?

The code that retrieves and sets the form geometry is roughly as follows:

```
def get_geom(frm):
        config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read('settings.cfg')
        x_pos = int(config.get('dialogPos', 'xpos'))
        y_pos = int(config.get('dialogPos', 'ypos'))
        h_dim = int(config.get('dialogPos', 'hdim'))
        v_dim = int(config.get('dialogPos', 'vdim'))
        frm.setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, h_dim, v_dim)
        # The move() function seems to "randomly" cause the form to crawl down/right 31x8 px
        # Without it, it "randomly" crawls up/left the same dimentions.
        frm.move(x_pos, y_pos)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick - updated to include the salient elements of the code. I have a suspicion that it relates to a parent somehow and interprets the x/y position as the position of the top/left of the title bar (which is what I want) or the top/left of the form contents (without the title bar).